# Compare String received by Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using a method to receive values from Bluetooth.

When I print the received values using Log.e, is possible to see the data, but when I try to compare the data, the condition fails.

I'm trying to compare the current data with 1 and 0, and even when the received data changes from 0 to 1, I keep receiving 0's. I tried to change from "==" to "equal", but it still not working

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void  beginListenForData()
{


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[200];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
            {
                try
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        if (data == "1") {
                                            anyObject = true;
                                            Log.e("Val 1", data);
                                        } else if(data == "0"){
                                            anyObject = false;
                                            Log.e("Val 0", data);
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what does 'data' variable contains? You said you loggin that data value. Could you please post that data value

Comment: The data contains 1 or 0

Comment: it means data variable is of string?

Comment: Yes, when I receive the bytes I convert it to string to be able to read it: data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");

Comment: did you try like this if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))?

Comment: It is unclear as to what is exactly in `data`. Try the equals as suggested by @AbdulWaheed , although you hint you have. And also, try trimming the value of data. Have you checked whats in `data`, character for charater, or is it an assumption its 0 or 1.  (aka, are there extra spaces ?? -> use `trim()`)

Comment: I used trim() and is working now, thank you, I was sending extra spaces.